# SQL: Count in a Left Join issue

Tags: sql, count, group-by, left-join, sql-like

This prints out what I'd expect it to, but I can't figure out how to count how many rows are in it

```
select distinct(post.city), zips.zip_code, zips.population, post.stabbr
from zips left join
     post
     on zips.zip_code=post.zip
where post.stabbr like 'MO' and zips.population > 5000 and
      post.longitud > (select avg (zips.lon) from zips where state_prefix like 'mo' )
group by post.city;
```

I thought

```
select count(*)
from zips left join
     post
     on zips.zip_code=post.zip
where post.stabbr like 'MO' and zips.population > 5000 and
      post.longitud > (select avg (zips.lon) from zips where state_prefix like 'mo' )
group by post.city;
```

would work, but it printed all 41 rows and I believe the city's `grouped by`.

Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)` with no `group by`:

```
select count(distinct post.city)
from zips left join
     post
     on zips.zip_code=post.zip
where post.stabbr like 'MO' and zips.population > 5000 and
      post.longitud > (select avg(zips.lon) from zips where state_prefix like 'mo' );
```